# Как построить гистограмму, на которой разные классы отображаются разными цветами

Tags: excel, гистограммы

Нужно построить одну диаграмму. На рисунке набросал как это должно выглядеть.

Берется модель машины, откладывается по Х. Ее скорость по Y. В зависимости от того, к какому классу принадлежит автомобиль, будет определяться цвет столбца.

В файле *test.xlsx* создал пример. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать в *Excel*? Если нет, то какими инструментами можно воспользоваться?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот файл: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/OZHZLj-o7ySNcQ

Answer (score 0):

Диаграмма - **гистограмма с накоплением**. Каждый столбец такой гистограммы содержит в себе значения всех рядов (в данном примере - двух). Если заполнить все ячейки таблицы, в каждом столбце будут отображены по два ряда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разносим данные на два столбца - *class 0* и *class 1*, т.е. скорость автомобиля указываем только в столбце нужного класса. По прежнему каждый столбец содержит в себе два ряда, но ряд, где значения нет,  попросту не виден - высота нулевая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные для гистограммы - `Лист1!$B$3:$D$6`

Данные рядов - `Лист1!$C$4:$C$6` и `Лист1!$D$4:$D$6`